# Selenium doesn't open browser. springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver

Selenium doesn't open browser
automatically.
Besides this, I ran other example code and it didn't work.

This code may be wrong because it's my first time doing a spring boot. However, copying other successful examples did not work the same.

I searched for Stack Overflow solutions but it doesn't run.
I'd really appreciate your help.

```
package com.ptuproject.ptuproject.Controller;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class SeleniumController {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public void process() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.kr/");

    }

}
```

**Output**

[image]

build.gradle

```java
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.1.2'
    }
```

Comment: it might be due to headless mode for application servers. I suggest to put this before spring context is started and check if it works         System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");